# Convert data from wide format to long format in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I have some data in the format:

```
VAR1 VAR2 Score1 Score2 Score3
A     B    1      2      3
```

I need to convert it into the format

```
VAR1 VAR2 VarName Value
 A     B  Score1   1
 A     B  Score2   2
 A     B  Score3   3
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: What is `value` supposed to represent?

Comment: Please give more information about the structure of your data. Are the snippets you've posted column names or values? Where does `Value` come from?

Comment: Have made the changes. Please check

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provided your score columns are fixed and you require no aggregation, you can use multiple `SELECT` and `UNION ALL` statements to generate the shape of data you requested. E.g.

```
SELECT [VAR1], [VAR2], [VarName] = 'Score1', [Value] = [Score1]
FROM [dbo].[UnknownMe]
UNION ALL
SELECT [VAR1], [VAR2], [VarName] = 'Score2', [Value] = [Score2]
FROM [dbo].[UnknownMe]
UNION ALL
SELECT [VAR1], [VAR2], [VarName] = 'Score3', [Value] = [Score3]
FROM [dbo].[UnknownMe]
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f54b2/4/0

Comment: ERROR: column "varname" does not exist in table

Comment: Is there another way of doing this if there where more Score variables?

Comment: Simple and easy.. it worked!

Answer (score 2):

In hive, you could use the `named_struct` function, the `array` function, and the `explode` function in conjunction with the `LATERAL VIEW` construct

```
SELECT VAR1, VAR2, var_struct.varname, var_struct.value FROM
(
  SELECT 
    VAR1, 
    VAR2, 
    array (
         named_struct("varname","Score1","value",Score1),
         named_struct("varname","Score2","value",Score2),
         named_struct("varname","Score3","value",Score3)
    ) AS struct_array1
  FROM OrignalTable
) t1 LATERAL VIEW explode(struct_array1) t2 as var_struct;
```