# Reshape data wide to long in Hadoop Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

My wide data look like this:

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is long:

[image]

I have many Score_X's and each score has many items. So the less hard-coding (e.g. [Convert data from wide format to long format in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792629/convert-data-from-wide-format-to-long-format-in-sql)) the better.

I have thought about a few ways to do this; unfortunately `Hive` does not have many features that other `SQL` implementations have. So first I would appreciate a solution to my problem, and secondly, if anyone knows easy ways to emulate these things in `Hive` please do share with me.

1. The `pivot` function, which `Hive` doesn't have.
2. I tried to apply Joe Stefanelli's answer in [Selecting all columns that start with XXX using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797686/selecting-all-columns-that-start-with-xxx-using-a-wildcard). `Hive` does not have `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` either. I was told (also by stackoverflow) that I could get table metadata by first installing `MySQL` and then detour through `MySQL`; I don't feel like spending that much effort on a simple task like reshaping a table...
3. Then I think I can combine the values of Score_A_1, Score_A_2 and Score_A_3 into one Score_A array and then do a `LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE` like in myui's answer in [How to transpose/pivot data in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive). But I Googled around and could not find a tutorial to do that.

Thanks. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Update:
So the `array` function will create an array column from multiple columns. Now I am doing the `LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE`; through hard-coding (i.e., non-dynamic query) I am getting what I want. However it is difficult to believe that there is not a simpler way to perform a data management task as basic as reshaping. Am I missing something fundamental about `Hive`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive - Unpivot functionality in hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621970/hive-unpivot-functionality-in-hive)

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-transpose-data-in-Hive/answer/John-Martinez-41